# Calculate total winnings and losses for a betting system

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to calculate winnings, losses, and profit based on a betting system with the following rules:

- If you bet and win, your winnings are your original bet + 1/2 the bet
- If you lose, you double your bet for the next round (martingale system)

Here's what I have

```
int initialBet = 30;
int currentBet = initialBet;
int totalWinnings = 0;
int totalLosses = 0;
int totalProfit = 0;
int i = 0

do {
 if (win) {
   //you win back your bet + half your bet, i.e. bet=30, win=45, profit=15
 }
 else //loss
 {
   totalLosses += currentBet; //you lost your full current bet
   currentBet = currentBet * 2; //Double your next bet to win back your money
 }
i++
} while (i < 100);
totalProfit = totalWinnings + totalLosses;
```

What should be in my "win" scenario to properly track this?

Comment: I assume you can win some number of partial dollars, so you may want to store the dollar values in `decimal`s, rather than `int`s.

Comment: The flaw in the Martingale system is that you occasionally lose your entire bank (assuming a finite bank, which is how life is). This solution has no check to see if you are hitting that limit (unless you have 3.8 * 10^31 dollars). This model therefore has a major flaw.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
if (win) {
    totalWinnings += (int)Math.Floor(currentBet * 1.5);
}
```

If you're trying to analyze a betting strategy, it seems like you'd want to do something with `currentBet` when you win, but you haven't specified that here.

Also as [*Grant Winney*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639542/calculate-total-winnings-and-losses-for-a-betting-system/21639587#comment32703075_21639542) points out, you probably meant to calculate `totalProfit` like this:

```
totalProfit = totalWinnings - totalLosses;
```